# How to export CMake property and set it differently in install(EXPORT …)

Tags: cmake

I'm setting up a CMake based build system for an old framework, written in C. It consists of a single binary, some core libraries and many dynamically linked libraries, which are built against the core libraries. All the libraries require a custom code generation step, which generates C code from model files, written in a domain-specific language. The code generator reads the library's own model file as well as those of all dependency libraries.

My goal is to structure those libraries in several CMake projects ("base framework", "extension libraries" and application specific projects), supporting three scenarios (with the same code base):

- Including base framework and extension libraries as sub-projects (i.e. git submodules) into an application specific project. In this case, those CMake projects are included via `add_subdirectory()` and are part of one single CMake project.
- Building application specific projects against the base framework's build tree. Public library header files and model files for code generation should be read from the source tree.

  This can be achieved by using `export(EXPORT foo FILE FooFrameworkConfig.cmake)` in the base framework's CMakeLists and `find_package(FooFramework)` (with an appropriate `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`) to include the CMake properties of the base framework's build targets into the application project.
- Building application specific projects against the base framework's install tree (without having the sources available). All required public header files and model files for code generation are copied to the install tree via appropriate `install(…)` rules.

  To include the CMake properties of the base framework's build targets into the application project, I tried to use `install(EXPORT foo FILE FooFrameworkConfig.cmake)` in the base framework's CMakeLists and the already mentioned `find_package(FooFramework)` (with an appropriate `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`).

To manage the model search paths for the code generator, I introduced a custom CMake property on the library targets (let's call it `FOO_MODEL_PATHS`). This property contains the paths to the model files of the library itself and all its dependency libraries. I made this custom property exportable via `set_property(TARGET ${OV_LIBRARY_NAME} APPEND PROPERTY EXPORT_PROPERTIES FOO_MODEL_PATHS)`.

Unfortunately, I cannot get it working for the third scenario. In this case, I need this custom property to be set to different values in the install tree export file (generated by `install(EXPORT …)`) and the base framework's build system. For CMake's internal properties, one can use the `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:…>` and `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:…>` generator expressions for this purpose. However, for custom exported properties, generator expressions are forbidden (see [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/prop_tgt/EXPORT_PROPERTIES.html) and [this commit](https://gitlab.kitware.com/yrHeTaTeJlb/cmake/commit/6db61f072588bb097b16094290b0b415fa4905e5#9a5a0b03fa1a219c965f7c368987017dbef214ab_1100_1127)).

So, how can I manage the code generator's search paths in CMake and share them to the dependent projects via EXPORTs, but fix them in the generated `install(EXPORT …)` file?

Comment: just brainstorming: could you create a wrapper install script that `include()`s the generated `install(EXPORT)` file and overrides those properties? I haven't tried this, but I think it's worth a shot.